# Split list of urls into seperate lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, url

I am trying to separate a list of URLs into separate lists depending on the name. I have these URLs:

```
['www.example.com/name/0900','www.example.com/name/1000','www.example.com/name/1130','www.example.com/name1/0900','www.example.com/name1/1000','www.example.com/name1/1130','www.example.com/name2/0900','www.example.com/name2/1000','www.example.com/name2/1130']
```

I am trying to separate them based on the name variable. This is my desired output:

```
['www.example.com/name/0900','www.example.com/name/1000','www.example.com/name/1130']

['www.example.com/name1/0900','www.example.com/name1/1000','www.example.com/name1/1130']

['www.example.com/name2/0900','www.example.com/name2/1000','www.example.com/name2/1130']
```

I found this answer [Split a list of urls with similar pattern into dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349448/split-a-list-of-urls-with-similar-pattern-into-dicts) but it doesn't output the way I need it and I can't work out how. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the complete set of expected names? Will the URLs always respect the pattern <base_url> / variable_of_interest / number?

Comment: it goes <base-url>/variable/variable1//variable2/variable_of_interest/number/variable3.  I need it to sort by the variable of interest and go from low number to high number if that makes any sense

Comment: Does the result need to be a list like that, or can it also be `['0900', '1000', '1130']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one approach using `str.split` and storing in `dict`

**Ex:**

```
data = ['www.example.com/name/0900','www.example.com/name/1000','www.example.com/name/1130','www.example.com/name1/0900','www.example.com/name1/1000','www.example.com/name1/1130','www.example.com/name2/0900','www.example.com/name2/1000','www.example.com/name2/1130']
result = {}
for url in data:
    result.setdefault(url.split("/")[1], []).append(url)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'name': ['www.example.com/name/0900',
          'www.example.com/name/1000',
          'www.example.com/name/1130'],
 'name1': ['www.example.com/name1/0900',
           'www.example.com/name1/1000',
           'www.example.com/name1/1130'],
 'name2': ['www.example.com/name2/0900',
           'www.example.com/name2/1000',
           'www.example.com/name2/1130']}
```

Comment: Never seen `dict.setdefault` before. This is great!

Comment: This works perfectly but is there any way to add each of those lists into separate lists without the name part at the beginning?

Comment: `list(result.values())`?

Comment: Thanks for the help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out by iterating them and checking with a simple condition:

```py
al = ['www.example.com/name/0900','www.example.com/name/1000','www.example.com/name/1130','www.example.com/name1/0900','www.example.com/name1/1000','www.example.com/name1/1130','www.example.com/name2/0900','www.example.com/name2/1000','www.example.com/name2/1130']
name = [name for name in al if 'name/' in name]
name1 = [name1 for name1 in al if 'name1/' in name1]
name2 = [name2 for name2 in al if 'name2/' in name2]
```

So when you print it you will get:

```py
>>> print(name)
['www.example.com/name/0900', 'www.example.com/name/1000', 'www.example.com/name/1130']
>>> print(name1)
['www.example.com/name1/0900', 'www.example.com/name1/1000', 'www.example.com/name1/1130']
>>> print(name2)
['www.example.com/name2/0900', 'www.example.com/name2/1000', 'www.example.com/name2/1130']
```

Comment: @AnnZen but it also depends on how big your context is. So its helpful sometimes but yes one can easily understand them and develop something of their own by referring them.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
a = ['www.example.com/name/0900','www.example.com/name/1000','www.example.com/name/1130','www.example.com/name1/0900','www.example.com/name1/1000','www.example.com/name1/1130','www.example.com/name2/0900','www.example.com/name2/1000','www.example.com/name2/1130']
b = {}

for elem in a:
    name = elem.split("/")[1]
    try:
        b[name].append(elem)
    except:
        b[name] = [elem]

print(b)
```

This is the easiest way to do separation without knowing how many separate link names you got.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how you can use `sorted()` with a custom key:**

```
import re

a = ['www.example.com/name/0900','www.example.com/name/1000','www.example.com/name/1130',
     'www.example.com/name1/0900','www.example.com/name1/1000','www.example.com/name1/1130',
     'www.example.com/name2/0900','www.example.com/name2/1000','www.example.com/name2/1130']

b = sorted(a,key=lambda c:c.split('/')[-2])

d = len(re.findall('name/',''.join(b)))

e = [b[x:x+d] for x in range(0,len(b),d)]

print(e)
```

Output:

```
[['www.example.com/name/0900', 'www.example.com/name/1000', 'www.example.com/name/1130'],
 ['www.example.com/name1/0900', 'www.example.com/name1/1000', 'www.example.com/name1/1130'],
 ['www.example.com/name2/0900', 'www.example.com/name2/1000', 'www.example.com/name2/1130']]
```

Answer (score 0):

To include generalising the positioning of the variable_of_interest and the number, sort by number, and return a list of lists:

```py
# Specify positions of variable/number of interest
i_var = 1 
i_num = 2

# Split by variable of interest (per Rakesh's excellent answer)
result = {}
for url in urls: 
    result.setdefault(url.split("/")[i_var], []).append(url)

# Sort by number
out = []
for key, values in result.items(): 
    out.append(sorted(values, key=lambda x: x.split("/")[i_num]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import defaultdict


data = [
    'www.example.com/name/0900', 'www.example.com/name/1000',
    'www.example.com/name/1130', 'www.example.com/name1/0900',
    'www.example.com/name1/1000', 'www.example.com/name1/1130',
    'www.example.com/name2/0900', 'www.example.com/name2/1000',
    'www.example.com/name2/1130'
]

output = {
    'name': [
        'www.example.com/name/0900',
        'www.example.com/name/1000',
        'www.example.com/name/1130'
    ],
    'name1': [
        'www.example.com/name1/0900',
        'www.example.com/name1/1000',
        'www.example.com/name1/1130'
    ],
    'name2': [
        'www.example.com/name2/0900',
        'www.example.com/name2/1000',
        'www.example.com/name2/1130'
    ]
}

name_index = 1

result = defaultdict(list)

for url in data:
    name = url.split('/')[name_index]
    result[name].append(url)

assert output == result
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to make a variable first like `example = ['www.example.com/name/0900','www.example.com/name/1000','www.example.com/name/1130']`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.